# How can I convert string data to time obejct?

Tags: r, time-series

my dataset is "irregular_sensor". but class(irregular_sensor$X1) is character. How can I transform it to date with scrptime() function?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
irregular_sensor <- data.frame(X1 = c("05/16/17 10:34 AM", "05/16/17 03:23 PM", "05/16/17 08:45 PM"))

irregular_sensor$X3 <- strptime(irregular_sensor$X1, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")

irregular_sensor
#>                  X1                  X3
#> 1 05/16/17 10:34 AM 2017-05-16 10:34:00
#> 2 05/16/17 03:23 PM 2017-05-16 15:23:00
#> 3 05/16/17 08:45 PM 2017-05-16 20:45:00
```